# How to Resize UIToolBar from a UIDatePicker?

Tags: swift, uikit

I'm trying to show a UIDataPicker when the user clicks on the UITextField. It works. However, the size of it seems ridiculous.

[Please, check this image from the simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrERC.jpg)

It gives a warning regarding the constraints I've used in the storyboard:

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000036017c0 'TB_Trailing_Trailing' H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x7fa478418640'Cancel']-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7fa478418470 )>

```
func showDatePicker() {
    // Format date
    bdPicker.datePickerMode = .date
    
    //ToolBar
    let toolbar = UIToolbar();
    toolbar.sizeToFit()
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(donedatePicker));
    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancelDatePicker));
    
    toolbar.setItems([doneButton,spaceButton,cancelButton], animated: false)
    
    BDTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    BDTextField.inputView = bdPicker
}
```

I tried to modify: toolbar.sizeThatFits() and I gave random values, but the app crashed. So, I'm looking for a strategy that I can make this UIDatePicker fits half of the page at least.

Comment: In simulator, keyboard is hidden by default. you can enable keyboard by IO -> Keyboard -> Connect Hardware Keyboard or try Toggle Software Keyboard.

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati I did so. But even the keyboard doesn't show up when the user is inside the UITextField. I think it's not even supposed to be showing up since there's a UIDatePicker connected to this UITextFiled.